# There's a way to avoid AppleStore?

Tags: iphone, itunes, distribution, adhoc

i need to develop an iPhone application that is a Client of serverside application. This application is not for customer but for sell agents. I know that if i try to send to Apple to put on Apple Store they reject it because the application have no sense for Apple Store. The company is small so i can't use the Enterprise program. The only way i can use now is to use Ad Hoc mode but in this case if i made an update you need iTunes and i must find a way to avoid this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure that Apple will reject it? There are a lot of applications which do not make any sense already in App Store.

Comment: This is a Businness application. The applications that u say make silly things so are good foe AppleStore but this application doesn't do anything if u don't have a working account. So is useless.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use cocoa? You could maybe build an html application that users can add to their desktop. Webkit allows you to have a client side database, in case you need to use it offline.

Comment: This isn't my choice, if i can choice i don't make it for iPhone so i must find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your application would be rejected by the Store.
For my employer, I developed a client side application that uses an appliance (server side) that my employer sells.

We provided a public appliance (with a public IP) to Apple in order to enable them to test our client application by entering the public IP of the server into the settings of the application.

They tested it, approved it, and our application is now "ready for sale" even if such application is useless for most of the appstore clients who don't own one of our appliance server.

Comment: Thanks, the trick is, when you submit your app, there's a part "demo account" in the submission form in which you can put the special settings your app needs in order to work properly with a special environment. This part will be used by the Apple test team to test your app.

Answer (score 1):

The only option you have is ad hoc distribution, as you mentioned, which will allow you to provision up to 100 devices that can install the application.

As for updating, there is no automated way for you to do this. A new version of the app will nee to be emailed to each device owner and installed manually via iTunes and sync.

Comment: I'm thinking about to add a slider to see to product that the agents sell if you haven't a working account so the application become a catalogue if you are a "Guest" or let work you if you are an agent. Maybe this can make Apple happy and my application can go to Apple Store. May work?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to say in that comment (sorry... it's difficult to understand). If you mean you'll allow the app to run in two modes, a catalogue for customers and a fully featured sales app for agents, then I think that could be a solution. I don't see why Apple would reject that. There are plenty of apps in the app store that don't work if you don't have an account.

Comment: Sorry for my english. Yes, this is what i'm trying to say. I will try this way. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

http://www.fancyfon.com/index.php/famoc.html

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Grassino87,

there's a formal way created by Apple: your client must register as a enterprise company.
They will not able to sell application to AppStore, but they can deploy their application to their employees: it's called "In-House Distribution".

You can find more details here: http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/

Using standard AdHoc method will limit potential sell agents to 99 device...

Comment: Target companies must have at least 500 employees

Comment: As mouviciel said, this is the little limitation of this way :)

Answer (score 0):

May be it's not the true way, but you can use [testflight](http://testflightapp.com). There you could target your sales persons as testers and provide new update via weblink-shortener. For us it work seamlessly. Plus there's a nice API to find problems in your app.